# Flatten collection of collections using CompositeCollection?

Tags: wpf, compositecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` with a number of `MyParent` objects, that in turn have their own `ObservableCollection` of `MyChild` objects. Now I want to show *all* `MyChild` objects in a grid view, which naturally asks for a flattened collection.

[CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) looks promising.

**Q:** Is it possible to wrap an arbitrary number of collections in a `CompositeCollection`?

If not, are there alternatives?

Comment: CompositeCollection does allow you to add arbitrary number of collections and elements but that may not be required. I can also recommend @sheridan's answer for your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use any `CompositeCollection` to do what you want. You can extract all of the `MyChild` objects from all of the `MyParent` objects using the [`Enumerable.SelectMany` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) in a simple `LinQ` query. Try this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var children = YourParentCollection.SelectMany(i => i.MyChild).ToList();
```

If you're not familiar with these `Enumerable` extension methods, you should definitely investigate them.

Comment: What if the collections are changed (e.g. Add/Remove). Will the update logic work using this method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but this code will select *all* of the `MyChild` objects from *all* of the `MyParent` objects that are currently in the `YourParentCollection`. It's not a lot of code... why don't you just try it?

Comment: I believe he's asking whether collection change events from the source collections will propagate through the result, to which the answer is no.  `CompositeCollection` will propagate the events, though.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, that's correct! It's indeed a quite complex problem once you cannot use the `CompositeCollection` class. I believe the best approach would be to write a custom CompositeCollection class... sigh :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a converter like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var parent = value as IEnumerable<Parent>;

    // Note: CompositeCollectionView not support grouping。
    var compositeCollection = new CompositeCollection();

    foreach (var child in parent)
    {
        var collectionContainer = new CollectionContainer {
            Collection = child.SomeCollectionProperty;
        };

        compositeCollection.Add(collectionContainer);
    }

    return compositeCollection;
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this will propagate changes in each ```child.SomeCollection```, but the view will become stale if the parent collection is modified, or a child changes their ```SomeCollection```. I feel in order to work with the general WPF databinding pattern, this should respond to ```INotifyCollectionChanged``` events on ```value```, and ```INotifyPropertyChanged``` events on each ```child```.